# How to add a new key value to react js state array?

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I want to add new key value to array ınto state? I tell you what I want to do below. How can I do that?
1. Start state in consruture method

```
`this.state = {
    files: []
}'
```

2. After I doing set state with active files

   this.setState({files: activeFiles})
3. Screen my state

   `{
       files: 
       [
           {
               key1: val1,
               key2: val2,
               key3: val3
           },
           {
               key1: val1,
               key2: val2,
               key3: val3
           },
           {
               key1: val1,
               key2: val2,
               key3: val3
           }
       ]
   }`
4. How to add new key value for each file? 
   The state I want

   `{
       files: 
       [
           {
               key1: val1,
               key2: val2,
               key3: val3,
               key4: val4
           },
           {
               key1: val1,
               key2: val2,
               key3: val3,
               key4: val4
           },
           {
               key1: val1,
               key2: val2,
               key3: val3,
               key4: val4
           }
       ]
   }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think This will meet the above scenario.

```
const newFile = this.state.files.map((file) => {

    return {...file, key4: val4};
});
this.setState({files: newFile });
```

Comment: Doesn't this mutate the state?  @duwalanise

Comment: Actually this does. I was so silly I will update this one, Thanks @FabricioG

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of `forEach` and add the new value like

```
var newState = [...this.state.files];
newState.forEach(function(file) {
  file.key4 = "val4"
})
this.setState({files: newState}, function() {
  console.log(this.state.files);
})
```

**Fiddle**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        files: 
        [
            {
                key1: "val1",
                key2: "val2",
                key3: "val3"
            },
            {
                key1: "val1",
                key2: "val2",
                key3: "val3"
            },
            {
                key1: "val1",
                key2: "val2",
                key3: "val3"
            }
        ]
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.files) ;
    
    var newState = [...this.state.files];
    newState.forEach(function(file) {
      file.key4 = "val4"
    })
    this.setState({files: newState}, function() {
      console.log(this.state.files);
    })
  }
  render() {
    return <div>Hello</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```