# How to setState while adding a key value into each array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to set state while adding a key value to the array.  I've followed several questions including this one: 
[How to add a new key value to react js state array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609615/how-to-add-a-new-key-value-to-react-js-state-array/41609800#41609800)

I can't get any of those answers to work with my challenge.

My state is like this:

```
this.state = { jsonReturnedValue: [] }
```

when componentDidMount() I make a fetch request and I added new state and a foreach loop (as based on the instructions from the question above)

```
  componentDidMount() {

    let newState = [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue];
    newState.forEach(function(file) {
      file.selected = "false"
    })

    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/printing/postcards-printing')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
      this.setState({ jsonReturnedValue: [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue, ...json.printCategory.products] }, () => console.log(this.state));
      })
      .then(this.setState({jsonReturnedValue: newState}, () => console.log("selected added" + this.state) ));
  }
```

I was thinking that I would just setState again with the key value pair so I added the .then the third time but it's not working.

the final console log returns this: `selected added[object Object]`
Digging more into it I see the object is empty.

EDIT: My goal is to set the state with the api call but also add key value of "selected: false" to each array.

Comment: the console log will look like that no matter what because you're trying to concatenate a string and an object. so if you change the log to `console.log('selected added', this.state)` does it still come back incorrect?

Comment: Not much of this makes sense. You just want to set the state when the fetch call completes?

Comment: My goal is to add the api call to state but also add the key / value of "selected: false" to each array @Jared Smith

Comment: `.then(this.setState`  your using `then` incorrectly, then expects a function callback.  eg.. `.then(() => this.setState(....`

Comment: you should describe in your question what kind of data structure gets returned from the api and what should state look like after it's updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`componentDidMount` only runs once, the first time the component is mounted, which is before your data call. After you fetch your data and call `setState`, the [update lifecycle methods](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#updating) are run.

Assuming you are on a new version of React, you'll want to intercept your state change in [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops):

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  // `state` will be the new state that you just set in `setState`
  // The value returned below will be the new state that the `render`
  // method sees, and creating the new state here will not cause a re-render
  return state.jsonReturnedValue.map((file) => {
    file.selected = "false";
    return file;
  });
}
```

Now, Ideally you don't actually want to do that there, but instead do it once you fetch your data:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/printing/postcards-printing')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        // NOTE: it's unclear from your post exactly what the data structure is
        // Is it product.file, or is `product` also `file`?
        const products = json.printCategory.products.map((product) => {
          product.file = "selected";
          return product;
        });

        this.setState(
          {
            jsonReturnedValue: [...this.state.jsonReturnedValue, ...products],
          },
          () => console.log(this.state)
        );
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

should probably be something like this

```
function addSelectedFalse(array) {
    return array.map(item => ({
        ...item,
        selected: false
    })

fetch('endpoint')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({ jsonReturnedValue: [...addSelectedFalse(this.state.jsonReturnedValue), ...addSelectedFalse(json.printCategory.products] }))
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding you want to fetch a products array and add `selected: false` to each product before setting state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        products: []
    }
}
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/printing/postcards-printing')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
        const { products } = json.printCategory;
        for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
            products[i].selected = false;
        }
        this.setState({products});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an idea working:

https://codepen.io/ene_salinas/pen/GYwBaj?editors=0010

```
  let { Table } = ReactBootstrap;

  class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      this.state = {
          products: []
      }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      console.log('componentDidMount..')
      fetch('https://api.github.com/users/xiaotian/repos')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(output => {
          let products = []
          for (let i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
              products.push({selected:false,name:output[i].name})
          }

          this.setState({products},() => console.log(this.state))

      })

    }

    render() {

          return(<Table striped bordered condensed hover>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Selected</th>
                <th>Name</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {this.state.products.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                    <tr><td><input type="checkbox" checked={item.selected}/></td><td>{item.name}</td></tr>
                ) 
              })}
            </tbody>
          </Table>)
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <Example />, 
    document.getElementById('app')
  );
```

Hope to help you!